# Integral involving varying area of surface

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let's look at the discrete case first. I have the pmf $p$ for some random variable $X$. For every realization $X=x$, I get a surface $S(x)$, for example, it could be the disc $\bar{B}_0(x)$. Looking at the discrete case first, I have the sum

$I=\sum_k p(k) |S(k)\setminus S(k-1)|$

I'm struggling how to write the integral in proper notation for when $X$ is a continuous random variable and $p$ is its pdf, for an arbitrary "continuous" surface $S(x)$.

Comment: Is it a set difference or a symmetrical difference $S(k) \Delta S(k-1)$ ?

Comment: Why not think in terms of level sets ? See "co-area formula" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula). Not sure that it helps...

Comment: @JeanMarie it is set difference. So for the discrete case, we're taking the average of "donuts", but for the continuous case, I want to integrate the area of $\bar{B}_0(r)\setminus \bar{B}_0(r-dr)$. I looked at the link, but I don't have any measure theory background so I didn't really get it.

Comment: If you have a differentiable contour, the integral you are looking for is due to contain a term involving the normal to the curve.